# EditText in ListView?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-listview

I am using this code for getting the value of edittext in a list view.

```
     View view = listview.getChildAt(position);
     EditText text = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.myEditBox);
     String contents = text.getText().toString();
```

But the problem is that when i scroll the list view ,position changes and i am getting a different result.i.e if i scroll,the element at fifth position gets at the top and its position becomes 0.Is there any remedy for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to create an Adapter for your listview if you haven't already done that, and on your adapter when you set your views add a textwatcher and report when the text is changed to your activity or fragment.

On your adapter:

```
edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                        int after) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    ((MyActivity) getContext()).textChanged(s.toString());

                }
            });
```

On your activity

```
public void textChanged(String s){

       //do somthing with the string
}
```

That way you don't have to guess the position fo your edit text

Comment: But how will i determine that which row's edit text value I am getting.

Comment: if you implement your adapter getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) method, you also get the position of the item you are currently working, so you could easily pass a new parameter to the textChanged method of your activity